# What serious alternatives exist for the IOStream library? (besides cstdio)

Tags: c++, iostream

I'm looking for a library which operates similar to iostreams, in that it performs conversions, and allows writing to memory buffers, files, and the console. However, I'd like something type safe, as iostream is. Are there any serious libraries which do this?

Being able to specify the output encoding for things would be a plus.

Note that I'm not interested in libraries which simply front iostreams because they just add *more* complexity to what iostreams is doing, e.g. `boost::format`.

PreEmptive comment response: I don't want to use cstdio because using that system it's impossible to have code be output location agnostic. That is, you have to call one function for sending things to buffers, and you have to call another function to send things to files, and another for the console, etc.

EDIT2: In response to the flurry of comments below: I'm fed up with both iostreams and cstdio. Here are more specific reasons. I tried to keep my "rant" out of this question, but people keep asking my if I'm off my rocker, so here's my rationale.

#### cstdio

- Can't handle Unicode characters correctly
- Can't write into something like a string without doing manual buffer management
- Often requires support of nonstandard extensions (e.g. `vsnprintf`) in order to be usable (EDIT: Okay, C99's standard library being in C++11 adds most/all of these now)
- Can't change the location of output without changing the original code (nonstandard extensions e.g. in glibc allow you to treat a file pointer as a buffer, which kind of does this... but it's still just that, a nonstandard extension)
- Makes security "fun" (to the point where entire chapters are dedicated in security docs explaining issues, e.g. with "printf"'s format strings and such)
- Not type safe

#### iostreams

- Slow
- Entirely too complicated to a client. If you use only what comes with the standard library it's great, but attempting to extend things is next to impossible. I read the entire "Standard C++ IOStreams and Locales" book -- the only book seemingly available on the topic -- *twice* -- and I still don't know what's going on.

I love iostreams in concept, even the use of `operator<<` which some people seem to not like, but it seems entirely too over engineered to me. Someone should not have to spend countless hours reading books in order to be a simple client of your library. Sure, if you're adding a new output source or something like that I could understand, but.... clients should be shielded from that complexity. (Isn't that what a library's for?)

This is about the only thing that's painful in C++ that "just works" in other programming languages, that I see no reason to be complicated.

Comment: "and because writing your own `operator<<` is... an interesting task to do correctly" -- how so?

Comment: The performance reasons are often exaggerated - actually I found out that on recent implementations iostream can outperform stdio. On the other hand, I agree that iostream is not very well designed, and a nicer alternative would be worth considering.

Comment: @Xeo: You have to save the state of the stream, use those "sentry" things to handle errors, check exception specifiers to determine whether or not to throw, restore the state of the stream no matter what, etc. I don't want all that complexity.

Comment: Some people have _way_ too much free time on their hands. :-)

Comment: @pax: I'm confused. What do you mean?

Comment: @Billy: Wasn't `sentry` needed only if you manipulated directly the `streambuf`?

Comment: @Billy: Restore state -> RAII, and mind giving an example (ideone?) of a "complicated" `operator<<` overload?

Comment: @Matteo: To be honest, I don't know. However, the more and more I look at this the more and more I think "this is an awfully complicated way to handle what's essentially ToString in other languages".

Comment: @Xeo: I don't have any examples. I've never seen anyone attempt to do it correctly, however. I see a lot of *attempts* at doing it correctly, but few seem to do the error handling right, or restore the stream state correctly.

Comment: @Billy: to be honest, actually I never understood half of the classes involved in iostream, `sentry` included. :) And I heard from many people that, even if they were designed to achieve flexibility, they even fail at this in almost every real-world scenario.

Comment: By the way, I know of the [Boost.Iostreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) library, but I have never really looked at it, does anybody know if it's any good also for "normal" file IO?

Comment: `operator>>` was always where I always felt the complexity just got out of hand. So I don't mind the o part of iostreams, but a new i would be awesome.

Comment: +1 Good question, and I doubt you're going to get a good answer. Nothing that will give you rest, anyway.

Comment: @Matteo for the little I understand, boost.iostreams defines concepts for standard iostreams, to ease extending them. but i don't think they fix the formatted input and formatted output hell.

Comment: @Billy: Firstly, creating a stream state guard object's a one liner, and if your way of checking re exceptions and throwing isn't the evil macro's an option. Secondly, with the "v" version of printf/scanf-family functions, you can trivially create a single wrapper function that will handle various output targets. That said, neither option's great. I've seen lots of companies with home-grown "fast_xstream" classes, but none in Open Source libraries, and none were more complete or better designed than `iostream` anyway - just a little faster for having cut functionality.

Comment: @Tony: Problem with the "v" version of those functions is that they are not standard, and therefore I can't rely on them.

Comment: @Tony: How exactly is creating a state guard object a one liner? It's certainly not in the standard library. I know boost has something that will do it but I think it's a little insane to have to pull in a large third party library to use iostreams correctly.

Comment: @Billy: from a man page: "... vprintf(), vfprintf(), and vsprintf() functions conform to ANSI X3.159-1989 (``ANSI C89'') and ISO/IEC 9899:1999 (``ISO C99'').  ... snprintf() and vsnprintf() functions conform to ISO/IEC 9899:1999 (``ISO C99'')."  Not good enough?

Comment: +1 interesting question, as I wondered the same thing recently...of course with me that equates to considering writing my own alternative, whether that's really a good idea or not.

Comment: @Tony: Yes, not good enough. C99 != C++. C++ does not include all C99 features -- including those functions. I don't believe they are added in C++0x either.

Comment: @Billy: you create an class that preserves the stream state passed to the constructor and restores it on destruction.  So, 10 lines for the class, 1 line per usage.  No need to use boost for something so trivial.

Comment: @John: I almost considered writing something like that; unfortunately I don't have the time to do so. Hoped something existed that would do it already.

Comment: @Tony: Bigger problem with vsnprintf (which is really the function you'd be stuck using) is that it doesn't support wide characters correctly, IIRC. (Unicode support is not an optional thing nowadays) As far as the "write your own state saver" object is concerned -- I guess it's possible to do that. Okay, now you've got error handling, format field width, and `sentry` crap to deal with on top of it.... seems way too damn complicated for an operation that should be simple.

Comment: @Billy you don't need to maintain the stream's state in formatted input. if input fails then leave the stream in a failed state. no need to restore anything.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: `boost::format` basically adds a wrapper around iostreams -- it's still using the `operator<<` overloads and such to write things out. It's got both of the same weaknesses iostreams itself has (slow, complicated). I think it's a great library, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for here.

Comment: @Billy yes yes, you're right, i just thought about it a moment after i posted my comment. :-S  see my other comment above though: you don't always need to maintain error state. not in formatted input.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: it's the precision, dec/hex etc. state that's good to push/pop when stream works...

Comment: Are you sure C++ is the language for you?

Comment: @jeffamaphone: Yes. I like everything else -- it's this one particular library I dislike. C++ is complicated because it's powerful -- AWESOME libraries like the STL though show that the complication is worth it. Complexity is worthwhile when it results in flexibility; but other languages' stream implementations are much simpler, but just as flexible. (To be fair, C++'s streams predate pretty much everyone elses)

Comment: Ever found a solution to this problem?

Comment: @Shafik: Nope. Still a huge pain in the ass.

Answer (score 8):

[The {fmt} library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt): I just stumbled across it from a [YouTube talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ptba_AqFYCM) and it seems to be quite nice.

A formatting facility based on {fmt} has been proposed for standardization in C++20: [P0645](https://wg21.link/p0645). Both P0645 and {fmt} use a Python-like format string syntax which is similar to `printf`'s but uses `{}` as delimiters instead of `%`.

For example

```
#include <fmt/core.h>

int main() {
  fmt::print("The answer is {}.", 42);
}
```

prints "The answer is 42." to `stdout`.

The `std::format` function proposed for C++20:

```
#include <format>

int main() {
  std::string s = std::format("The answer is {}.", 42);
}
```

Notable features of {fmt}:

1. Type and memory safety with errors in format strings optionally reported at compile time.
2. Extensibility: users can write formatters for their types, including custom format specification parsers (as in Python).
3. Compact binary code. The print example above compiles to just:

   ```
   main: # @main
     sub rsp, 24
     mov qword ptr [rsp], 42
     mov rcx, rsp
     mov edi, offset .L.str
     mov esi, 17
     mov edx, 2
     call fmt::v5::vprint(fmt::v5::basic_string_view<char>, fmt::v5::format_args)
     xor eax, eax
     add rsp, 24
     ret
   .L.str:
     .asciz "The answer is {}."
   ```

   which is comparable to `printf` and much better than iostreams.
4. Performance: {fmt} is considerably faster than common implementations of `printf` and `iostreams`. Here are results from a tinyformat benchmark on macOS with clang:

   ```
   ================= ============= ===========
   Library           Method        Run Time, s
   ================= ============= ===========
   libc              printf          1.01
   libc++            std::ostream    3.04
   {fmt} 1632f72     fmt::print      0.86
   tinyformat 2.0.1  tfm::printf     3.23
   Boost Format 1.67 boost::format   7.98
   Folly Format      folly::format   2.23
   ================= ============= ===========
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the edit.. Yes the library is quite awesome.

Comment: Yeah FMT is the perfect combination of iostream like features and printf like syntax, but it doesn't have any functions to read input from console as far as I know.

Answer (score 7):

[Boost](http://www.boost.org/).[Spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/index.html).[Qi](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/quick_start.html) for input, [Boost](http://www.boost.org/).[Spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/index.html).[Karma](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/karma/tutorials/quick_start.html) for output. Can read from/write to anything that can be represented as an iterator range.

Comment: I like both of these libraries -- I don't think they can be general replacements for iostream though because 1. they both have horrendously bad compile times when compared with traditional libraries, and 2. good luck debugging the error messages you get in the event of a syntax error. Still a reasonable answer to my original question, so +1.

Comment: Streams were too complicated according to the OP, so now we use Boost Spirit?  Now we have two problems!

Comment: @John : By my understanding, the OP meant complicated in terms of ease of extension and runtime complexity/overhead. In both regards Boost.Spirit is unrivaled, so I stand by this answer.

Answer (score 6):

You might be interested in [**Fast Format**](http://fastformat.sourceforge.net) library. You can see the comparison on their website with various other libraries as well.

Comment: Wow.. this looks really really cool. Will have to play and see how things go with it

Comment: sadly the website doesn't appear to work and it requires STLPort which doesn't appear to be in great shape.

Comment: I'm unchecking this for now because of the dependence on STLPort (this prevented me from using it at the time) -- I will probably come back and check it again but I want some more experience using the library first. (The lack of maintenance recently isn't a good sign though)

Comment: Among other problems it is considered "alpha" and has an alarmingly empty website making me fear that the future may be uncertain. Nice pick though.

Comment: That's not STLPort, it's STLSoft (whatever that is and it doesn't appear to be in great shape either).

Comment: The link is broken, I think this is the new one: http://fastformat.sourceforge.net/ . On this line there is also http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/format/index.html .

Answer (score 0):

How about using [The fmt library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) and [The scn library](https://github.com/eliaskosunen/scnlib), fmt handles output quite well and scn can handle inputs. I've used both of these libraries at once and it's much less painful to use than standard(and it's readable!).

You should try them both out.