# How can I use std::hex for my custom uint128 type?

Tags: c++, hex

What is the correct syntax to overload (or whatever is actually is) `std::hex`, so that its functionality can be extended to non standard integers? i wrote this version of [uint128_t](http://calccrypto.wikidot.com/programming%3auint128-t)

Comment: If your compiler supports uint128, then this is probably supported out of the box.

Comment: @calccrypto: Oh. Well then you should probably indicate that in your question, given that several compilers provide 128 bit integer primitives. MSVC++, for example, provides `__int128` when compiling as 64 bit.

Comment: Code review comment: I would make your `ULL`s in lowercase so that they don't look like part of the hex number. :)

Comment: @Billy ONeal, in lowercase `l` looks like `1`. Vote for uppercase :)

Comment: @Krill: Not in most programming fonts I've used. There's a `u` in between there anyway.

Comment: @calccrypto: another code review, I would avoid the implicit casts from `uint128_t`. You can reduce the amount of code in the linked file by making slight changes. Implement `operator X=` for any given operator `X` as a member function *but* implement `operator X` as a free function, that will enable the compiler to perform implicit conversions on the lhs, and that will make a bunch of the templates at the end of the code useless. Since there is a templated implicit conversion, you don't need to provide `template <typename T> uint128_t operatorX( T rhs ) { return *this X (uint128_t)rhs; }`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

std::hex is just a manipulator which set some of the formatting flags on the stream.  You can get them using ios_base::flags() and use the result in your operator<<.  You probably should also use ios_base::width and ios_base::precision.

If you want more settings than what is provided, ios_base::xalloc, ios_base::iword, ios_base::pword furnish a path to extensions for your manipulators and insertors.

Comment: +1. Man I hate all this complexity to add a simple user-defined formatter. At least [I found a better way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171360/what-serious-alternatives-exist-for-the-iostream-library-besides-cstdio).