# How can this line-by-line file reading be much slower in c++ than in Python?

Tags: python, c++, file, fstream

I have a 2GB file. An average line has 15 char (max 50). When using:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

void main()
{
    std::ifstream input("myfile.txt");
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(input, line))
    {
    }
    return;
}
```

it takes ~ 320 seconds, whereas this Python code:

```
with open('myfile.txt', mode='r') as f:
    for l in f:
        semicolonpresent = ';' in l        # do anything here, not important
```

takes less than one minute.

**What is wrong in the C++ version I'm using?**

Note: I've tried both many times, each one after a fresh reboot, or after many previous runs (so it might be in I/O cache), but I always get such order of magnitudes.

Note2: I compiled the C++ code on Windows 7/64, using:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
cl main.cpp
```

Comment: Did you compile with optimization turned on?

Comment: @Galik I edited question with compilation lines

Comment: well your python code has very little similarity with the cpp code. if you wat to compare performance, i recommend have them do the same thing. also using the c functions may be faster

Comment: It is `int main() {....return 0;}`

Comment: @JoshKisb Why little similarity? I used in both cases the natural way to read a file line-by-line. `with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f: for l in f: ...` for Python, and this for C++: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7868998/1422096

Comment: `cl main.cpp` lacks most of fancy arguments that can be used by compiler. You better create program using default VS console application template. And don't forget to select `Release` configuration when building.

Comment: I can't reproduce these results using `Linux`and `GCC 7.2`,in my tests `C++` is much faster (about 5 times faster over apprx `1GB`)

Comment: Did you try comparing the times just opening the large file in C++ and Python and not  reading the lines ?

Comment: @VTT I'm usually using command-line + text-editor only, so I'm not familiar about VS, and these `cl` arguments. Which are they usually?

Comment: I recall a very similar question about ruby in the last few days, it turned out to be a difference between optimized and non-optimized build. As soon as the c++ compiler was set to optimize the difference went away.

Comment: With more accurate timing and programing on my system `C++` is about `3` times faster over `1GB` but over `7GB` they are about the same (with `C++` in the lead by a few seconds).

Comment: Actually this task is not that good for performance comparison because it is mostly io-bound. python technically can call the same C functions as C++ to perform actual reads, while nobody really uses iostreams to read files in C++.

Comment: @VTT `nobody really uses iostreams to read files in C++` then I was misinterpreting  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/read-file-line-by-line/7868998#7868998. How would you read line-by-line a big file in C++?

Comment: I mean that nobody really uses them in real life applications, not that they can not be used at all. See [What serious alternatives exist for the IOStream library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171360/what-serious-alternatives-exist-for-the-iostream-library-besides-cstdio) for example. The lack of proper io routines in C++ is a serious language pitfall that forces devs to look for alternatives. Unfortunately standard committee is too busy with adding stuff like emojis syntax or Riemann zeta functions. I would use home-brewed mmap or async reading wrappers.

Comment: @VTT We'd love to prove Riemann hypothesis with C++ code :)

Answer (score 1):

In my tests `C++` is not slower than `Python`. Over a large binary file they are about the same.

I modified your code a little to provide what I feel should be accurate timings.

**Python code**:

```
import sys
import time 

start = time.time()
sum = 0
with open(sys.argv[1], mode='r') as f:
    for l in f:
        sum = sum + 1
end = time.time()

print "(", sum, ")", (end - start), "secs"
```

**C++ code**:

```
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    std::ifstream ifs(argv[1]);
    std::string line;

    unsigned sum = 0;
    while(std::getline(ifs, line))
        ++sum;

    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    auto time = double(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count());

    OUT("( " << sum << " ) " << (time / 1000.0) << " secs");
```

Processing a `7.1 GiB` binary video file gives:

```
Python: ( 32547618 ) 62.9722070694 secs
C++   : ( 32547618 ) 63.368 secs
```

The `C++` code was compiled on `GCC v7.2` using the following flags:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -O3 ...
```

By contrast unoptimized code ran in `68.541 secs`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you add details about how you compiled (compilation parameters, optimization, etc.), because I noticed it changed a lot the timing.

Comment: @Basj Sure I added the optimization level. In my tests they didn't make much difference. It seems the larger the file the less the difference between different methods. I would expect this because the most time is spent waiting for the disk to spin :)

Answer (score 0):

`void main` isn't valid C++. Neither is an empty `return` in `main()`. Also, with optimizations turned on, your `while` loop will be optimized away. With that said...

You should notice a speed improvement if you turn optimizations on. However, streams in C++ are slow. This is not news to the C++ world. So why is Python much faster? The two are not really equivalent. Python is written in C and internally delegates to C library functions. Further, it's likely that Python is allocating a buffer in advance and copying the buffer in one go. If you wanted to do something similar in C++:

```
std::ifstream ifs(filename);

auto end = ifs.tellg();
ifs.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
auto beg = ifs.tellg();

std::string buffer;
buffer.reserve(end - beg);
std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs),
          std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
          buffer.begin());
```

Comment: How to turn optimization on with `cl helloworld1.cpp` ?

Comment: Doing `buffer.reserve(end - beg);` might not end well if there isn't enough spare ram to allocate solid 2 GB block.

Comment: @Basj [`cl` optimization flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/o-options-optimize-code). A basic one would be `cl /O2 helloworld1.cpp`, though by default I'm pretty sure it already uses `/Ot`, which uses a set of speed optimizations.

Comment: In my tests streams are not slow, they perform basically the same as the underlying `OS` calls (`Linux` systems).

Comment: @VTT The worst that can happen is an exception is thrown.

Comment: @user9183966 The idea of reading line-by-line (instead of reading the whole file in memory) is to avoid to load a big space in RAM. Let's say each line just updates an `int` state variable in the loop. Then the whole thing shouldn't should more than 1 MB in RAM, even if the file is 2 GB. So I don't really see why you're using a buffer, reserve, etc.

Comment: @Galik *In my tests streams are not slow, they perform basically the same as the underlying OS calls (Linux systems)* Get faster disks and a system with more memory bandwidth.  If you're running commodity hardware, disk IO seek times are likely very poor, and memory bandwidth is likely limited.  That can hide the overhead of streams processing. Most computer buyers don't look past the CPU and the amount and speed of system RAM.  Even for buyers who look at the drive(s), very few look at the disk controller. Streams processing likely stays entirely in the CPU and the on-board cache, masking it.

Answer (score 0):

(Partial) answer:

As mentioned by many people in comments, `cl` [optimization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1ack8f1.aspx) helped:

```
cl /Ox helloworld1.cpp
```

divided the runtime by 6!